# What is this "Account Update" progress bar?

Tags: accounts, popup-ads

This pop up appeared for me just now. I hit <kbd>esc</kbd> and it disappeared but it was super puzzling. How would I even know what that was?

It just said "Account Update" and "Account update in progress" with no other indication of what account was updating.

[image: Screen shot of account update]